# prevent opening an html file on multiple browser tabs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, browser

I have an html file. I don't want to open that file too many times in one browser. if in the browser I already have that html file open. then when opening another tab with the same htm file, an error will appear. Is there any way to do that?. we can use javascript, html, jquery or any other way.

Comment: No, their is no reliable way to do this. Why would you want to?

Answer (score 2):

The only reliable way I can see to do this is to listen to a message asking "Am I here?" on a [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) and respond with "I am here.". At page load, ask "Am I here?" and if you get the positive response, you'll know another tab already has your page.

```
const bc = new BroadcastChannel("Tin huynh's Broadcast Channel");
const question = "Am I here?"
const answer = "I am here."
bc.onmessage = evt => {
  if (evt.data === question) {
    bc.postMessage(answer)
  } else if (evt.data === answer) {
    alert("I am already here.")
  }
}
bc.postMessage(question)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JavaScript to check if the HTML file is already open in the browser before opening it in a new tab.

```js
function openHTMLFile() {
  var isFileOpen = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < window.length; i++) {
    if (window[i].location.href == "https://yoursite/path/to/file.html") {
      isFileOpen = true;
      break;
    }
  }


  if (!isFileOpen) {
    window.open("https://yoursite/path/to/file.html", "_blank");
  }
}
```

Comment: Another comment already said this before, but for some reason it is gone: `window.length` is number of sub-frames in the current window, not number of open windows or tabs in the browser: you cannot check the addresses of other tabs this way.